# Autocomplete and linting with class methods defined in separate file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint, pylint

I have written a class in python 3.8 and for reasons, I need some of the class methods to be defined in a different file. The method I used for putting this function as the class method was by adding it later with setattr. This allows me to selectively add methods I want, I wont get into too many details on that because its irrelevant

myClass.py:

```
# This bit will scan the external file and add relevant methods to the class via a decorator
# just to give an idea, don't get hungh up on the implementation
def add_methods():
    def decorator(Class):
        import methods from external.py
        for method in external.py:
            if method is what I want:
                setattr(Class, method_name, method)
@add_method()
def myClass():
   def __init__(self):
      dostuff
   def method_1(self, arg1 , arg2):
      dostuff
   def method_2(self, arg1 , arg2, arg3):
      dostuff
```

Inside another folder, we got the method file I mentioned
method_folder/external.py

```
def ext_added_method_1(self):
    do stuff here
def ext_added_method_2(self):
    do stuff here
```

Then finally, the class is used by a code
main.py

```
from myClass import myClass

handler = myClass()
dostuff
```

This all works just fine, the externally added methods are there and work just as expected. but there is one annoying bit that is when I'm working on the 'external.py' file which is where most of the coding is done anyway. My VSCode understandably does not know what is inside of the 'self' parameter of ext_added_method_1 and ext_added_method_2, so there is no linting.

The question is, is there a way of telling vscode, that on external.py, the 'self' parameter should be linted from the myClass object?
I don't need linting of the methods inside external.py (ext_added_method_1 and ext_added_method_2) I know that would be impossible since they are dynamically added. But for the methods that are defined in myClass.py, such as method_1 and method_2 I would like to have autocomplete and all that magical stuff.

Any way to achieve that without changing the architecture?

thank you!

Comment: you could add type hints to external but then you need to import `myClass`, the decorator does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

Thx rioV8m, I wasn't familiar with that term. But then I looked it up and came up with the following solution

external.py

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        from myClass import myClass

def ext_added_method_1(self: 'myClass'):
    do stuff here
def ext_added_method_2(self: 'myClass'):
    do stuff here
```

With that import check, I have no issues with circular imports so it basically ignores that, but is enough for VSCode to pick up on the class.
Also, I add the type in single quotes which are called 'forward references'. This is then only used by the editor to inform it of the class contents.